# Are these two references semantically equivalent?

Tags: alloy

The introductory example from *Software Abstractions*:

```
sig Name, Addr{}
sig Book {
    addr: Name -> lone Addr
}

pred show(b:Book) {
    #b.addr > 1
    #Name.(b.addr) > 1 
}
```

Would **#Addr > 1** be semantically equivalent with **#Name.(b.addr) > 1**?

It confuses me **Name** is a general set reference while **b** refers to particular books and they appear in an expression together. Furthermore, what does the bracketed **(b.addr)** expression exactly refer to?

Answer (score 2):

`b.addr` is the mapping for address book `b`, from names to addresses. So `Name.(b.addr)` is the image of the set of all names under that mapping: it's the set of addresses in `b`. Thus `#Name.(b.addr) > 1` says that address book `b` contains more than one address. In contrast, `#Addr > 1` says that there exists more than one address -- which would be satisfied by having addresses that don't belong to any book at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me take the chance and congratulate you and your team for the brilliant approach and the wonderful tool.